# In a C# TBB: how to split a multi SingleLineTextField into seperate strings

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

I have a plain textfield in Tridion that can have multiple values. The itemtype is a SingleLineTextField.

In the TBB code I have the following (removed the non-essential parts):

```cs
ItemFields itemFields = new ItemFields(folder.Metadata, folder.MetadataSchema);

foreach (ItemField itemField in itemFields)
{
    string itemFieldValue = string.Empty;
    switch (Utilities.GetFieldType(itemField))
    {
        case FieldType.SingleLineTextField:
            itemFieldValue = itemField.ToString();
            break;
    }
}
```

Now the result in case of two entries is just two strings with a character line break in it.

```
String A
String B
```

The method used is a generic one, which also works on other fields, so I was looking for some way to find out if a SingleLineTextField has more values in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cast the field to a `SingleLineTextField` type, then iterate through the Values collection, something along these lines:

```cs
SingleLineTextField field = (SingleLineTextField)itemField;
foreach(string value in field.Values)
{
    // do something with value
}
// or if all you want is the count of values
int i = field.Values.Count;
```

Comment: That's working!
Where I went wrong is to not cast the Itemfield specifically to the SingleLineTextField. It's only then that you get the "familiar" field.Values options...

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I would advise against relying on the `ToString()` method on objects unless it is specifically documented. In this case it works with the abstract class `ItemField`, but this may not always be the case.

The TOM.Net API only defines Definition and Name properties for `ItemField`, so you need to cast your ItemField object to something more specific.

the `TextField` abstract class, which `SingleLineTextField` inherits from, defines a `ToString()` method, but also `Value` and `Values` properties, which are much better suited to what you're trying to do. Looking at the documentation, we can see that `Values` will give us an `IList<String>` of the values, even if your field is not multi-valued. Perfect!

So, to answer your question, "I was looking for some way to find out if a SingleLineTextField has more values in it", you need to cast your ItemField as a TextField and check the number of Values it provides, thus:

```cs
TextField textField = (TextField)itemField;

// If you need to deal with multi-valued fields separately
if (textField.Values.Count > 1)
{
    //Logic to deal with multiple values goes here
}
else
{
    //Logic to deal with single valued goes here
}

// Much better... If you can deal with any number of values in a generic fashion
foreach (string value in textField.Values)
{
    // Generic code goes here
}
```

Comment: Nuno wrote his answer while I was typing mine.
They are basically the same. I hope mine gave some additional context :)

Comment: Thanks @David, This is some nice additional information that will be useful to anyone else who might be having a similar issue. That's the whole point of SE!